# supervisor redis exception on docker

Tags: laravel, docker, supervisord

I used Docker and this is my config file.

```
COPY ./workers/conf.d /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
COPY /workers/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
RUN supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

and this is my env file

```
...
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=redis // service name in docker
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

**While my driver is a database, the supervisor wants Redis.**

2021-07-06 07:30:05,150 INFO gave up:  entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
RedisException

php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:141

simple worker for run queue

```
[program:laravel-worker-subset]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/mlm/api/artisan queue:work --queue=subset   --tries=3 --daemon
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/mlm/api/storage/logs/subset.log
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Comment: `RUN` instructions are executed when _building_ the image, not when starting the container; was your intent to temporarily start those services while building the image, or did you mean to start them when running your container? If "when starting the container", it should probably be `CMD`, not `RUN` (`CMD` is the default command that's started when running the container). https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: @thaJeztah CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"] not working

Comment: @thaJeztah CMD["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"] not woking

Comment: @thaJeztah CMD supervisor -n -c  /etc/supervisord.conf not woking

Comment: Does this setup work better if you avoid supervisord, and run one process in a container?  You should be able to use the unmodified Docker Hub `redis` image rather than installing it yourself.

Comment: Yes, running services in separate containers (and, e.g. a `docker-compose` file to define the services and container settings) is generally the recommendation (but without the full context, it's a bit hard to tell exactly what's the expectation here)